# null: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response; when using threads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, http-headers, httpresponse

I have a numebr of threads (let's just say 2 for now). from inside them, I am accessing a function named `ExportCSVSingle(string mac)` what this does is, it creates a `.csv` file for a specific thread. but it crashes at the `var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;` saying response is `null`. The code works fine if I use it without threads. I tried using the `mutex locking` which I already was when storing it in the db, but it did not work.

I will post only the relevant and short code below:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetCloudDevices()
         {
                var macList =  db.Mac.ToList();
        foreach (var g in macList)
         {
Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
          if (isConnected)
                {
                    mutex.WaitOne();
                    //...
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //CSVmutex.WaitOne();
                    ExportDailyCSV(g.Mac);
                    //CSVmutex.ReleaseMutex();
                   //where g.Mac is a string like abc-1-1
               ...// }   mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

Now the function:

```
public void ExportDailyCSV(string machine)
        {
            //CSVmutex.WaitOne();


            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var list = (from o in db.Logs
                        where o.Machine == machine && o.sDate == DateTime.Today
            select o).ToList();
            var fileName = machine;

            sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}", "No", "Name", "Time", "Mode", "Mac", "Ex", "type", "sid", "work", "sDate", Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}", item.No, item.Name, item.Time, item.Mode, item.Mac, item.Ex, item.Type, item.SId, item.Work, item.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), Environment.NewLine);
            }

            try
            {
                //Get Current Response  this is where it throws the exception
                var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.BufferOutput = true;
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
                response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
                //response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", fileName));
                //response.AddHeader("content-disposition", fileDetail);
                var attachmentValue = string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", fileName);
                response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachmentValue);
                response.ContentType = "text/csv";
                response.Write(sb.ToString());
                response.End();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                        Response.Write("Property: " + ex.ParamName + " Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            //CSVmutex.ReleaseMutex();

        }
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is per-thread.  Don't do that.

Comment: @SLaks what do I do instead?

Comment: Why are you using threads at all?

Comment: @SLaks I am connecting to a number of machines (remotely) at the sametime, they have different credentials, for that I needed to do it using threads. Now I am trying to get the stored data in my localDB  in the form of .csv whenever a thread has made connection successfully.

Comment: in short words. "Connect to n number of machines every 10 minutes, fetch the data, store it in db then call a function to export that data in csv"

Comment: You should change your action to `await` a result from a thread and return an `ActionResult`.

Comment: @SLaks which function? and how? a little more enlightenment, perhaps with an example would help alot!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access `HttpContext.Current` from any other thread (what if there are two requests at once?)

You should rewrite your code to separate your data logic from the HTTP response.

Specifically, you should move all of the data logic to a standalone function that returns `Task<T>` (use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to set its result from the other thread).

Your controller action should then `await` that task and put its result in an `ActionResult`.

Comment: `what if there are two requests at once?` but Im using `mutex.WaitOne();` and `mutex.ReleaseMutex();` to make sure only one thread uses that function at one time. even then?

Comment: @MickJagz: No; I mean which response would it send to?

Comment: pardon me, but iteratively all the responses?